# Status 500 – Internal Server Error On Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat9

I have error as Status 500 – Internal Server Error in my JSP when i try to post request.
So i need to do http request for creating folder on Dropbox with some name(Test, etc.)
I have Tomcat 9.0.30 and add jstl-1-2.jar
i have a Class DropboxActioner as

```
package ua.oleh.application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class DropboxActioner {
    private  String token ="Bearer <my token>";
    public void createFolder(String path) throws Exception {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/create_folder");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String parameters = "{\"path\": \"" + path + "\"}";
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.addRequestProperty ("Authorization", token);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            writer.writeBytes(parameters);
            writer.flush();
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And if i try it with public static void main it works.
I need to do this with web page where i need to enter token and folder name.
For test i don't get this parameters from JSP and write it static in code.
I have JSP page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DropboxDemo</title>
</head>
<body>
Enter token
<input id ="key"></input>
Enter folder Name
<input id ="folder_name"></input>
<button id="login">Login</button>
<button id ="create">Create folder</button>
<%@page import="ua.oleh.application.DropboxActioner" %>
<% DropboxActioner dropboxActioner = new DropboxActioner();%>
<% String token;%>
<% String name = request.getParameter("name");%>
<%= dropboxActioner.createFolder(name)%>
</body>
</html>
```

And i get e error on Chrome

```
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [18] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)
15: <% DropboxActioner dropboxActioner = new DropboxActioner();%>
16: <% String token;%>
17: <% String name = request.getParameter("name");%>
18: <%= dropboxActioner.createFolder(name)%>
19: </body>
20: </html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:519)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:139)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

i look a guide on Youtube where programmer get data from method in Java class with

```
<% DropboxActioner dropboxActioner = new DropboxActioner();%>
<% String token;%>
<% String name = request.getParameter("name");%>
<%= dropboxActioner.createFolder(name)%>
```

But i have an error.
How i can resolve it?
Maybe i can only read data from jsp/html to Java class and run it in public static void main and don't connect jsp page with Java class?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
<%= dropboxActioner.createFolder(name)%>
```

says out put the value returned by the call `dropboxActioner.createFolder(name)`.

But you have declared `createFolder` as returning `void`.  So the JSP can't print it.

> How i can resolve it?

Change the method to *return* the string that you want to be output.  The method is currently writing stuff to standard output.  That is probably going to end up in a log file.

> I need only create folder.  So i need convert void to String and return some string like "finish" etc?

That would be one approach.  Another would to replace the `<%=` with `<%` so that it doesn't try to render the (non-existent) output from that method.

Comment: i need only create folder. so i need convert void to String and return some string like "finish" etc?

Comment: Just use `<%` and not `<%=`.

Comment: @dan1st - I just said that :-)

Comment: Just a TL;DR :)